# Trying to match function declarations in code using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match function declarations in a string using code below

```
 // Functions with function fnName(){}
 var functions = fn.match(/function+[\s\S][.a-zA-Z0-9]+[\s\S]/g);
 console.log(functions);

 // Functions with var fnName = function(){}
 var functions = fn.match(/var+[\s\Sa-zA-Z0-9_$=]+function/g);
 console.log(functions);
```

But this is unable to catch signature properly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've after `+` after `var` and `function` and are using `[\s\S]`, which I suppose should be `\s*`. You can match both type of declarations with this regex

For `function name(..){...}` you could use

```
/function\s*\w+\s*\([^)]*\)\{[\s\S]*?}/g
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/fV6gP4/2)

and for `var name = function(...){...}`, you could use

```
/var\s*\w+\s*=\s*function\s*\([^)]*\)\s*\{[\s\S]*?}/g
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/fV6gP4/3)

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but it throws invalid Regex. Apart from that it does not match function(a){ console.log(a); }.

Comment: `[\s\S]` is white space and not white space, effectively `/./`. Probably `/(^|\W)function(\s|\W)/` is sufficient.

Comment: @RobG It is there for `\n`

Comment: @RobG and it removes the need for `s` flag. You can check it by replacing `[\s\S]*` with `.*` and you can see in the demo that it won't work. Anyway, I'll just include the flag

Comment: /\s/ should match '\n'. If the OP is trying to match the entire function body, then I don't think that can be done reliably with a regular expression. The code needs to be parsed.